# trouble downloading silverlight virtual earth map control

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, google-maps-api-2, virtual-earth

I'wanna downlaod Virtual Earth Silverlight Map Control CTP . but i can"t find this product anywhere ! even in Microsoft connect, it's  swiched by  Bing map !  can  any one help Me ?.
 PS: im intersting by Virtual Earth Silverlight Map Control CTP because i need to use google map Routing service . i now that it exist in bing map but its less rich than google map .

```
       ` <m:Map/>
      xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VirtualEarth.MapControl;assembly=Microsoft.
       VirtualEarth.MapControl"
      Width="500" Height="350">
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
      <m:Map></m:Map>
     </Grid>
    </UserControl>  `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont find the CTP release anywhere, and Virtual Earth is just the old product name for bing maps. You can get the version 1.0 of the Bing Maps Silverlight control (which is what the CTP turned in to) from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2949.

But from the sound of your enquiry you shouldnt be using Bing Maps/Virtual Earth control at all as you cannot (due to licensing) mix mapping services from Bing and Google.

Instead take a look at the open source silverlight mapping control:

http://deepearth.codeplex.com/